# What is the best way to copy large files from my workstation to a Windows Server based EC2 instance?

Tags: windows-server-2008, amazon-ec2, file-transfer, amazon-s3

I would like to know if there is a better way to transfer data from my workstation to my Windows based EC2 instance.  Currently I am using remote desktop copy/paste, but that is a drag as I always forget that I have the "data" on my clipboard and that a copy action will hose my transfer.  I really do not want to install any software on the host machine or open a a port.  Is there anyway for me to upload to S3 and then have the server mount the S3 volume?  I really like to be able to do something native to Windows & EC2.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't care about security you could simply setup FTP.  If you wanted to be more secure you could use sFTP (secure FTP) or SCP (Secure Copy).

Not a perfect answer; neither of those options are as simple as you might prefer as they require a bit of setup time.

update: 
To copy files through RDP you'll need to setup your RDP clinet so you can see your local resources. It's in the Options>Local Resource Tab>Local Devices/Drives area.

You won't be able to naviate to them via command line; you can use xcopy the command line.  e.g. xcopy \tsclient\C\FilesToBeCopied*.* C:\DestinationFolder\

Comment: Unfortunately that involves installing software (even if it is just a windows feature) and opening ports, which the op has stated they don't want to do.

Comment: If you're connecting via RDP you should be able to do some of the copying via command line which would at least free up your clipboard.

Comment: how can one copy via the command line over RDP?    That sounds pretty good to me.

Comment: I am going to accept the updated part of your answer, the first part requires more setup than I wanted.  Mapping the drives sounds pretty good, although that would require me to expose a little more of my local system to the amazon cloud that I would like...but I guess all things being equal, its the best choice.